# Capture packets using pyshark on remote server

Tags: python, pyshark

I am trying to capture packet on a remote server (which is a cluster node in my case). the cluster requires an ssh key to access it.

```
.
.
.
   def start_capture(self):

        self.capture = pyshark.RemoteCapture(remote_host= self._host,remote_interface= self.interface,bpf_filter='not port 1235',remote_port=self._port)
        self.capture.sniff(timeout=600)
        print(self.capture)
```

The RemoteCapture() doesn't have pkey parameter, so I m getting the error 'Test timeout 1 minute exceeded'.

Any idea how can I fix this